# Keyboard and mouse not working in X.Org - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, wayland, 18.04

I've recently done a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works fine except that when I log in using `Ubuntu` in the login dropdown menu (which is using X.Org) my mouse and keyboard are not working when I am logged in. However, when I log in using `Ubuntu using Wayland` it all works just fine.

Now I think there is a reason that X.Org is the default setting, so I would like to use it. Any suggestions on how to make my keyboard and mouse work?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 is Long Term Support (LTS) version. Thus stability is preferred and Wayland is probably considered relatively new technology (despite it is almost 10 years old). Older 17.10 already used Wayland in some cases with no problem, so I would recommend it over X.org, as it is much more modern and is expected to replace X.org entirely in near future.